# I get an error when I try to upload deobfuscation file

Tags: upload, deobfuscation

I'm trying to upload the mapping.txt to my new release. This isn't the first time I'm doing this, but I'm not a great expert at this either. I'd appreciate if someone could help me understand what's happening.

The outputs->mapping->release-> folder only has one file: mapping.txt

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The app needs to be published before the mapping files could be uploaded. But the files should be uploaded immediately. The reason being that any crashes that occur before the mapping file is uploaded will not be deobfuscated.

I hope this helps someone. If I'm wrong, please correct me on this.